# Android ProgressDialog stops spinning before the task is completed

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

I am using progress dialog in my Asynctask class on onpreExecte() method, and dismissing the dialog in onPostExecute while google makes the routes of the map. My problem is the wheel in dialog is stopping after 2-3 seconds but my background process is still working.

```
    private class ParserTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MapaViagem.this);
        // setup your dialog here
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setTitle("Traçando Rotas");
        dialog.setMessage("Aguarde...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

    }

        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {


            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                PathJSONParser parser = new PathJSONParser();
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

            // traversing through routes
            for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
                polyLineOptions.width(4);
                polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
            }

            googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but are you running a task inside a task? Why do you need this?

Comment: @TheRedFox sorry I've edited the question

Comment: how do you know the task is still running? can you be more specific?

Comment: @TheRedFox I'm new to android development, I don't really know if the task is still running, I'm telling it because when the task starts the spinner is rolling and suddenly it stops, then after 2 or 3s the dialog disappears showing me the routes

Comment: add a log `Log.i(TAG,MSG)` before `dialog.dismiss();`, if this log appears at logcat, then dialog get removed, then the task is finished, and worked as expected, IF THE map still loading, then this is a connection issue, that map is being fetched from server, and this is not related to the task.

Answer (score 1):

You must put all the "procesing" code inside the `doInBackground`, that means all the code you have inside the `onPostExcecute`. Only the things that modify the UI should be in the `onPostExcecute` (like for example show a message to the user, change text of a `TextView`, etc.), else you will get your UI stucked.
I had the same problem and resolved it this way.

Hope it helps